# Modular DNA as a way of classifying numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I'm going to start with a few examples. I may need someone to help correct wording.

I'm going to write what I call the modular fingerprint of the following numbers. It's the list of the remainders of these numbers when divided by all primes smaller than the number itself:

$15\equiv$

$1\pmod{2}$, $0\pmod{3}$, $0\pmod{5}$, $1\pmod{7}$, $4\pmod{11}$, $2\pmod{13}$

So 15's list would be $\{1,0,0,1,4,2\}$.

17 -- $\{1,2,2,3,6,4\}$

51 -- $\{1,0,1,2,7,12,0,13,5,22,20,14,10,8,4\}$

**Question 1:**

Are there infinitely many numbers that begin with any certain fingerprint? For instance, there are infinite that begin with $\{1\}$: all the odds. There are infinite that begin with $\{1,0\}$: odd multiples of $3$. Are there also infinite numbers that begin with the same fingerprint as $51$?

**Question 2:**

If #1 is true, are these fingerprints continuous? For instance, is there at least one (and thus infinitely many) number for each possible starting fingerprint?

$\{0\},$

$\{0,0\}, \{0,1\}, \{0,2\}, \{1,0\}, \{1,1\}, \{1,2\},$

$\{0,0,0\}, \{0,0,1\}, \{0,0,2\}, \{0,0,3\}, \{0,0,4\}, \{0,1,0\}, \{0,1,1\}, \ldots, \{1,2,4\}$, etc.

Comment: Maybe "Modular DNA" would be a better name, since numbers share some root "genes"?

Comment: "Infinitely many numbers", not "infinite numbers".

Comment: @RobertIsrael Sorry. My besetting sin. Editing now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Key phrase: Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Ah, so #1 is proven true by the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Would this then as well prove #2? That there is proven to be a $x \pmod y$ set of solutions for every one of these possibilities?

Comment: Yes. (As long as the set of moduli for the Chinese Remainder Theorem are relatively prime, there is always a solution).